# click event doesnt get clicked in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having problem with jquery click event. Here is what my app does. User enters names in textfield. when he he clicks on add button then that name appears in contents div tag. This name also has a delete button. Now the problem is when user clicks on delete button it does not give any response. So how can I make this work?

Here is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/tSTEK/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="name" name="name" />
    <input type="button" class="addBtn" name="add" value="Add" />
</div>
<div class="contents"></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.addBtn').click(function() {
    var name = $('.name').val();
    var contents = $('.contents');
    var div = $('<div class="names"></div>');
    div.append(name);
    div.append("<button class='delete'>X</button>");
    contents.append(div);
    $('.name').val('');
});

$('.delete').click(function() {
    console.log('click');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way to do this would be to use the `on()` function:

```
$('.addBtn').on('click', function() {
    var name = $('.name').val();
    var contents = $('.contents');
    var div = $('<div class="names"></div>');
    div.append(name).append("<button class='delete'>X</button>");
    contents.append(div);
    $('.name').val('');
});

$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
    console.log('click');
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tSTEK/7/

Answer (score 0):

You can add the click event when you create the element:

```
 div.append("<button class='delete'>X</button>")
            .click(function(){
                console.log('click');
            });
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tSTEK/1/)

Or a better [alternative](http://jsfiddle.net/tSTEK/4/) is to use .live() or .on() (depending on your version of jQuery).

```
$('.delete').live('click', function() {
    console.log('click');
});​

$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
    console.log('click');
});​
```

Comment: Is there better way than this?

Comment: jQuery has an .on() (or older .live()) method to register events.

Answer (score -2):

use .live or .delegate

```
$('.addBtn').click(function() {
    var name = $('.name').val();
    var contents = $('.contents');
    var div = $('<div class="names"></div>');
    div.append(name);
    div.append("<button class='delete'>X</button>");
    contents.append(div);
    $('.name').val('');
});

$('.delete').live('click', function() {
    console.log('click');
});
```

or delegate

```
$('.addBtn').click(function() {
        var name = $('.name').val();
        var contents = $('.contents');
        var div = $('<div class="names"></div>');
        div.append(name);
        div.append("<button class='delete'>X</button>");
        contents.append(div);
        $('.name').val('');
    });

    $('.contents').delegate('.delete', 'click', function() {
        console.log('click');
    });
```

edit: dont use live use on instead!
but I would still go for delegate cause far to my knowledge it the best one performance wise

Comment: _"As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()."_ http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Suggesting `live()` is almost just as bad as suggesting a w3schools link nowadays! ;)

Answer (score -2):

You could use the Jquery live method and then just remove the parent element:

```
$('.delete').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});​
```

Heres the fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/tSTEK/9/

Comment: _"As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()."_ http://api.jquery.com/live/